# remove sub elements from xml using LINQ to XML

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml

I want to remove sub elements from an XML doc using LINQ to XML.

sample XML:

```
<MainElement>
<otherelement />
<removeElement att='1'>
<removeElement att='2'>
<removeElement att='3'>
<removeElement att='4'>
</MainElement>
```

I want the output to be

```
<MainElement>
<otherelement />
<removeElement att='2'>
</MainElement>
```

The structure(Schema) should remain as it is, and the selected element should remain in the XML doc.

the queries that I tried helps me find that element from the XML, however, how do I maintain the XML structure

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648221/deleteing-whole-sections-of-my-xml-file-in-c/1648232#1648232 for a solution to a similar problem involving filtering and removing sub-elements from document.

Comment: this works for single element only!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a query to find the nodes that you want to remove and remove them.

```cs
XDocument doc = ...;
doc.Root
   .Elements("removeElement")
   .Where(e => (int)e.Attribute("att") != 2)
   .Remove(); // removes all elements in this query
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I can find the elements to be removed, but was thinking of avoiding the loop, as the doc is huge!!

Comment: @Priya: Updated without the loop.  But it's still equivalent to using the loop.  It was mentioned nowhere in your question.  And what do you mean by "maintaining the structure?"  You'll be removing elements from the document, that is a big structural change.

Comment: @Jeff.. my apologies for missing that in the question. Also, by structural change I meant, the schema. yes this will also be a loop internally, though, it will be not explicitly in the code